# What alternatives are there to a gas boiler for private house?

Tags: boiler, natural-gas

I am looking for gas boiler alternatives for private house. At this moment I have found [solid fuel boiler](http://www.stropuva.lt/index.php?cid=400&lang=en) as replacement of gas one. Could someone suggest any alternative to gas technology or other (better) implementation of this one?

**ADDED:**

By the way I have found:

[Thermia's heat pumps](http://www.thermia.com/products/cooling-house.asp)

Comment: Why do you want an alternative to gas? Without knowing that, all you'll get is a list of possibilities, ranging from coal to solar.

Comment: @kdgregory the cost of gas is going to be too expensive in near future in my country. :( I am looking for an independence in this question. I have to find out any other proven implementations, that just work.

Comment: Invest in solar heating, solar panel combination.. high initial cost but returns after 10 years(just in time gas is too expensinve) can cut electrical/gas costs up to 50% if isntalled correctly.. but this is not always possible

Comment: Are the Russians cutting you off again?

Comment: @Chris Cudmore in short - yes, but situation is more complicated, knotty :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Fuel Sources

**Coal**

[image]

**Wood**

[image]

**Propane**

[image]

**Natural Gas**

[image]

**Oil**

[image]

**Electricity**

[image]

**Biomass Pellets**

[image]

**Sun**

[image]

**Earth**

[image]

**Nuclear Fission**

[image]

---

## Heat Transferers

**Gas**

[image]

**Liquid**

[image]

---

## Heating Systems

**Furnace**

[image]

**Boiler**

[image]

**Heat pump**

[image]

**Electric heater**

[image]

**Wood stove**

[image]

**Fire place**

[image]

**pellet stove**

[image]

**Tauntaun**

[image]

Comment: Nice post, but one note: while the Tauntaun will keep you warm, it may smell bad.

Comment: If you're not up for a [real tauntaun](http://www.mcsweeneys.net/articles/a-hoth-realtor-addresses-some-of-the-concerns-being-raised-over-his-decision-to-turn-han-solos-deceases-tauntaun-into-a-modest-studio-apartment) there's always the [sleeping bag](http://www.thinkgeek.com/geektoys/plush/bb2e/)

Comment: That was stellar.

Comment: And I thought they smelled bad on the _outside_